# Override Richfaces Css using Foundation

Tags: css, sass, richfaces, zurb-foundation

I am using `rich:calendar` and I want to override its css like below
`text-box` should have 11 column width (like `.small-11`)
 [image]

But I get following output

[image]

**SCSS**

```
*.rf-cal-inp {
    @include grid-column($columns: 11);
}

*.rf-cal-btn {
    float: right;
}
```

Actually `width` and `padding` Overridden like below

```
input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

What I want is to get override richfaces component using `!important`. How can I put `!important` for `width` and `padding` in my scss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to !important, have you tried simply using a more specific selector?

```
input[type="text"].rf-cal-inp {
  width: auto;
  padding: 1px 0;
}
```

You can also use `input[type="text"][id*="calendar"]` to target just those widgets.